# Is this the proper way to extend wiring from a split receptacle?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, receptacle, kitchens

I understand some of the basics like piggy backing on a receptacle to add additional ones but need some help with split receptacles.

I currently have a split receptacle in my kitchen that I would like to add a switch to so that I can control some under cabinet LED lighting that I will install. In addition I would also like to add 2 additional receptacles to my kitchen island off this same receptacle.

So to recap my original receptacle is a split receptacle that has a dual breaker which I understand adds 120V to top and 120V to bottom plugs. I would like to use this receptacle and convert the box to 2 gang box and add a new switch to control LED cabinet lights, and add 2 new (120v) receptacles to the island.

I have attached a diagram of what my old and new setup would be and what I think I'm supposed to do. Would some confirm whether this wiring is correct? Specifically, please check I am doing with the red wire.

[image]

Comment: Note, you can simply pigtail off the original outlet for the white wire, and then you only have 3 wires in your wire nut.  Same for the first added outlet—connect the black and white wires from the nuts in the 2-gang box to the appropriate terminals on the outlet, then use the other terminals to the last outlet.

Comment: Aside: You can get receptacles that are marked to indicate that one half is controlled by another device (Switch, timer, photocell, ... .), e.g. [this receptacle](https://store.leviton.com/products/20-amp-125-volt-marked-controlled-receptacle-spec-grade-self-grounding-ivory-cr020-1pi?variant=35318252803). (Both halves marked is also available.) I thought it would cut down on the confusion when someone can't get a lamp/fan/vacuum to work some of the time. The local electrical inspector came through, looked at it and asked what it was. When I explained it he thought it wasn't a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram looks correct. I assume the wire and breaker are sized correctly.

The original outlet will be split, with power supplied from the black and red wire separately.  You can leave the red wire as shown in the diagram.

The black wire then, obviously provides power to all outlets downstream and to the switch for the LED lights.

This gives you what you want. Great job.

Comment: Thank you for the information and confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea, which puts the double-source double-current capability of the wall outlet on the island too, for more balanced current draw:

[image: added MWBC to island]

The difference is to run /3+ground cable of the correct gauge to the island, instead of /2+ground. Then both breakers' power will be at the island.

Wire the black from the island /3 run to the black on the wall outlet. Red on the island run to the red on the wall outlet. Neutral and ground same as before. In the island, wire one outlet to the red wire, the other to the black wire, and neutral & ground common to both island outlets.

This will give double power capability to the island as well as the wall outlet. (Your original sketch, though correct, had the whole island running only from the black side of the wall outlet, which would limit island power usage, in combination with the black half of the wall outlet.)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was also considering this setup. The 2+ wire is already run so not sure if I’d want to re run although would your idea give me a superior setup? If it’s only used for maybe a laptop or to charge phones, or potentially for a blender once and a while. Thoughts?

Comment: For low-current items like chargers, the extra line won't be needed. For blenders, probably not needed too, as you'd probably have to run several blenders at once to overdrive the current draw for a few minutes. The extra line would be good if you wanted to put a microwave in the island, or an undercounter fridge.

Comment: If someone plugged in a vacuum at the island while the counter microwave was running, then the two circuits would help, if the two appliances were on the different lines.

Comment: Oh man I have another addition to my question here....So I just realized that I need the main "Split Receptacle" to also be a GFCI receptacle since its close to the sink. I purchased one but it only has ins for a black, white, and ground then has outs for load with a black and white wire....it does not seem to have an area for the red wire to make it a split receptacle. Do they have GFCI receptacles that allow for red split? Any help here would be helpful.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge and reading here and other places, no, they don't have GFCIs that can also handle split power like your outlet has.  A dual GFCI circuit breaker could do it. Alternatively, you could use two GFCI outlets in a dual-gang box to replace the split outlet in the single-gang box, one handling the black side and the other handling red, and the island fed off the load sides of one of the GFCI outlets.

Comment: I was thinking the same as you described with the two GFCI outlets although a bit differently...i was thinking of doing the two GFI but I can't have them in the same box since I have an outlet and a switch in the two gang. What I was thinking is using the red hot for the 1st GFI outlet on the wall then using the black in the wall box and pigtail over to the one in the island and adding the second GFI to the island like that. Would that work? is it okay if they 2 GFI are not in the same box?

Comment: I think that would work, yes.